# Case insensitive string and array(as string) replacement with using regex in Go

Tags: regex, go

I've have a case where I'd need to do a case insensitive replacement of strings in a Go (json)string. The replacements can be of the following cases

1. Search string: `SOME_SEARCH_STRING`; Replacement String `REPLACEMENT_STRING`
2. Search string: `"[\"SOME_SEARCH_STRING\"]"`; Replacement String `"[\"INTv2RPACS\"]"`

I have the following as my regex

```
pattern := fmt.Sprintf(`(%s)`, searchString)
pat := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)" + pattern)
content = pat.ReplaceAllString(content, replacementString)
```

The above seems to work fine when the search and replacement string values are simple string, but it is failing when the search are replacement values arrays (ex. #2 above). What should be the regex updates that I need to do to be able to replaces arrays  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [regexp.QuoteMeta](https://godocs.io/regexp#QuoteMeta) to quote meta characters in the search string.

```
pattern := fmt.Sprintf(`(%s)`, regexp.QuoteMeta(searchString))
pat := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)" + pattern)
content = pat.ReplaceAllString(content, replacementString)
```

Answer (score -1):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

type rep struct {
    from string
    to   string
}

func replace(str string, reps []rep) (result string) {
    result = str

    for i := range reps {
        rx := regexp.MustCompile(fmt.Sprintf("(?i)(%s)", regexp.QuoteMeta(reps[i].from)))
        result = rx.ReplaceAllString(result, reps[i].to)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    content := `
{
    "key_1": "SoME_SEArCH_STRING",
    "key_2": "some_some_SEARCH_STRING_string",
    "key_3": ["SOME_SEARCH_STRING"],
    "key_4": "aBc"
}`

    var replaces = []rep{
        {`["SOME_SEARCH_STRING"]`, `["INTv2RPACS"]`},// important: array replacements before strings
        {`SOME_SEARCH_STRING`, `REPLACEMENT_STRING`},
    }

    fmt.Println(content)
    fmt.Println(replace(content, replaces))
}
```

```
output:

{
    "key_1": "SoME_SEArCH_STRING",
    "key_2": "some_some_SEARCH_STRING_string",
    "key_3": ["SOME_SEARCH_STRING"],
    "key_4": "aBc"
}

{
    "key_1": "REPLACEMENT_STRING",
    "key_2": "some_REPLACEMENT_STRING_string",
    "key_3": ["INTv2RPACS"],
    "key_4": "aBc"
}
```